# Scroll jump to top with webkit overflow touch on Android

Tags: android, cordova, scroll

i'm making an app for ios and android using phonegap and html.
In my layout, i've a div with a list which have overflow content.
To be able to scroll it, i use -webkit-overflowscroll:touch; and the overthrow js polyfill for devices which doesn't support this feature.

This work very well on ios.

But on Android, i've a bug.
When testing on Android 4.1 which supports the feature "-webkit-overflowscroll:touch;",
the scroll work well the first time, but if i click on an item after scrolling, the scroll jump up, and i can scroll the list longer than the list size (so i can scroll down it to get the items disapearing from screen)
Like that the scroll has been double sized...

Here is the basic markup

```
<div class='page'>
   <div class="contain">
       <ul><li><a></a></li></ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

My List is fill dynamically by an ajax loading i apply to the .contain the css "overflow-y:auto;-webkit-overflow:touch;"

I scroll only the .contain div and not the body (which have the overflow hidden property)

any suggestion ?
thanks

Comment: Both iOS and Android are entirely different from each other. There are some features which Android API doesn't support. Post some code, it could help us to understand what you're actually doing.

Comment: I'm having this same issue. I think it might be related to page transitions as I don't get this behaviour when I create a static page without JS but with the same HTML and CSS structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem and in my case I've changed the class of the list item to show a down state. When I removed the code to do that, the list selection works fine.